# Implementing a delete node by index value for singly linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to write a function that deletes a node at the given index value.The index value is passed as a parameter.

Delete: this method deletes a node from the linked list. If an index is passed as a parameter, then the method should delete the node at this index. If no index is passed, then delete the first item in the list

So far I have:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, dataval=None):
    self.dataval = dataval
    self.nextval = None

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.headval = None
  def __str__(self):
    node = self.headval
    output = "[ "
    while(node != None):
      output = output + str(node.dataval) + ", "
      node = node.nextval
    if(len(output) > 2):
      output = output[:-2]
    return output + " ]"


  def delete(self, index=0):
    if self.headval is None:
      print("This list has no element to delete")
      return 
        
    if self.headval ==index:
      self.headval=self.headval.nextval 
      return 
        
    n=self.headval 
    while n.nextval is not None:
      if n.nextval.dataval==index:
        break
      n=n.nextval

    if n.nextval is None:
      print("Item not found in list")
    else:
      n.nextval=n.nextval.nextval
```

Right now instead of deleting the value at that index it just deletes whatever index has that value.How can I change that

Comment: When you write `if n.nextval.dataval==index:` you are comparing the `index` you search with the value of a node. Instead, you should compare with the index of a node! Initialise an index counter `i = 0`, then increment `i` by 1 at every iteration of the while-loop. Compare `index` with `i` instead of comparing it with `dataval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `delete` method:

(1) Change:

```
if self.headval ==index:
```

to:

```
if index == 0:
```

(2) And change:

```
if n.nextval.dataval==index:
```

...to:

```
index -= 1
if index == 0:
```